# How to select all

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, plyr

I have a data frame (dives) with a number of variables including:

```
     diveNum bottomTime 
[,1]    2       FALSE
[,2]    2       FALSE
[,3]    2       TRUE
[,4]    2       TRUE
[,5]    2       FALSE
[,6]    2       TRUE
[,7]    2       FALSE
[,8]    3       FALSE
[,9]    3       TRUE
[,10]   3       FALSE
[,11]   3       TRUE
[,12]   3       TRUE
[,13]   3       FALSE
```

For each unique diveNum, I would like to select all rows between (& including) the first and last time that bottomTime is TRUE, giving:

```
     diveNum bottomTime
[,3]    2       TRUE
[,4]    2       TRUE
[,5]    2       FALSE
[,6]    2       TRUE
[,9]    3       TRUE
[,10]   3       FALSE
[,11]   3       TRUE
[,12]   3       TRUE
```

ddply has been my friend for similar problems, and I can determine the first and last records of "TRUE" in each diveNum by first subsetting the data to only include cases where bottomTime is "TRUE" then running ddply:

```
dives <- dives[dives$bottomTime == "TRUE",]
bottomTime <- ddply(dives, .(diveNum), function(x) x[c(1, nrow(x)), ])
```

This gives:

```
      X  diveNum bottomTime
[,1]  3     2      TRUE
[,2]  6     2      TRUE
[,3]  9     3      TRUE
[,4]  12    3      TRUE
```

What I can't manage is to do something like use the row numbers of the first and last records of "TRUE" in each dive (stored in X) as indices to subset the original data frame. I've been struggling with this for some time any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dives)
dives[dives[, do.call(seq,as.list(range(.I[bottomTime]))),by=diveNum][['V1']]]
# or
dives[dives[,.I[cummax(bottomTime) &rev(cummax(rev(bottomTime)))],by=diveNum][['V1']]]
 # or
dives[,.SD[cummax(bottomTime) &rev(cummax(rev(bottomTime)))],by=diveNum]
 #or
dives[dives[(bottomTime),seq(.I[1],.I[.N]),by=diveNum][['V1']]]
```

An approach using `plyr::ddply`

```
 ddply(dives, .(diveNum), function(x,ind) {
       x[do.call(seq, as.list(range(which(x[[ind]])))),]
       } ,ind='bottomTime')
```

or using `dplyr`

```
dives %>% group_by(diveNum) %>% 
          filter(cumany(bottomTime) & rev(cumany(rev(bottomTime))))
```

Comment: So many ways to skin a cat! Your second   data.table   suggestion was the first to work on my data frame and it did exactly what I wanted so I went with that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the most optimal way, but in base R you could use `split` with `do.call(rbind, ...)`

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dives, dives$diveNum), function(x){
      w <- which(x$bottomTime)
      x[ w[1]:tail(w, 1), ]
      }))
#      diveNum bottomTime
# 2.3        2       TRUE
# 2.4        2       TRUE
# 2.5        2      FALSE
# 2.6        2       TRUE
# 3.9        3       TRUE
# 3.10       3      FALSE
# 3.11       3       TRUE
# 3.12       3       TRUE
```

As mentioned in the comments, a "smoother" approach would be to use `by()` and avoid the two calls `lapply(split(...))`

```
> do.call(rbind, by(dives, dives$diveNum, function(x) {
      w <- which(x$bottomTime)
      x[ w[1]:tail(w, 1), ]
      }))
```

I just like to make things more difficult than they actually are sometimes.

Comment: You've reinvented `by` again for the central part of this: `by(dat, dat$diveNum, function(x) {w <- which(x$bottomTime); x[ w[1]:tail(w, 1), ];})`

Comment: @thelatemail, but I'm an innovator!